# Downloading, updating & reloading file back to s3 using AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have 3 very simple individual python scripts using **`boto3`** library for downloading, updating & reloading the file back to s3 bucket in AWS, all working fine.

However, wondering if the same is possible using AWS Lambda function?
Your experience sharing is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts should work fine with AWS Lambda as long as they are fine with the following limitations:

- need at max 1536MB of memory
- need at max 512MB of temporary disk space
- finish in less than 5 minutes

For a full list of limitations of AWS Lambda have a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

You even could react to S3 events when using AWS Lambda, so e.g. execute a script anytime a new object is created in S3. Check out the documentation if you're interested in that: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-s3